# Can't see workflow foundation performance counters

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, performancecounter

im trying to use performance counters for workflows. In Performance Monitor there are two categories: WF (System.Workflow) 4.0.0.0 and Windows Workflow Foundation.

But neither category offers any instance to watch. MSDN tells me that performance counters are enabled by default and there should be *global* instance available.

I tried it on Windows XP and Windows Server 2008. I also tried it with workflow service (xamlx) and workflow ran by WorkflowApplication.

In workflow service scenario i added workflowruntime behavior with enablePerformanceCounters flag set to true. I can see WCF performance counters but not WF counters.

Nothing works.

Comment: Can you tell me which performance metrics you're looking for?

Comment: I tried to add whole category to performance monitor but there are no instances available. So its not the problem with individual counter but the whole category i think

Answer (score 1):

The WF (System.Workflow) counters are for WF3 not WF4. There is another set for Windows Workflow Foundation that should work with WF4.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, im using WF4